# reverse engineering of a checksumming function

Tags: gdb, reverse-engineering, checksum

I want to create a function to calculate the checksum of one data block just as it does for a commercial program. 
I have tried with gdb or REC decompiler, but it seems I have no skills enough to do it. What tools can I use to decompile this function?
Is there any other approach I can take, such as trying standard checksumming functions to see which one is being used?

Comment: I've heard good things about the hexrays decompiler, but haven't tried it myself, since it's pretty expensive.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no skills

Reverse engineering requires basic knowledge of assembly (unless you're reverse engineering Java, C# or other VM-based language) and general programming knowledge. Having that in mind, you can use:

1. Hex-Rays decompiler for Ida, but it's expensive
2. Plain Ida without the decompiler, which is free but lacks features
3. Plain ollydbg.

The process of searching for the hash function's location is going to be roughly the same for all options, though I believe Ida has much more intuitive interface than ollydbg. The difference is what happens once you have it - with Hex-Rays decompiler, you can decompile it to pseudo C and quickly have an overview of what happens under the hood. Without it, you need to carefully study assembly code.

Either way, be prepared for it to take some time and have patience.